# Widths donot change when using lower resolution in CSS

Tags: html, css, width, resolution

```
@media screen and (min-width: 300) and (max-width: 800px) {
#top {
    font-size: 200%;

}
#first {
    width: 30%;
    height: 20%;
    font-size: 120%;
    position: relative;
    top:40%;
}
#second {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    height: 20%;
    font-size: 120%;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;

}
#quote {
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
}
#bannertextb{
    font-size: 250%;
    margin-left: 0;

}
#sps {
    font-size: 180%;
    position: relative;
    top: -08%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#class {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#greek {
    font-size: 350%;
    margin-left: 0;
}
#banner {
    height: 30%;
}

}
```

I wish to change the widths when opened from a phone.But this doesnt seems to happen.
But when i re-size my browsers window, everything works fine..
You can view the whole website @- [This link](http://www.ronaksakhuja.com)

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the min and max width and then try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this tag inside your `<head>` of your html .

```
<meta charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, minimumscale=1.0" name="viewport">
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code instead of your `media query`

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 300px) and (max-device-width: 800px){
//your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)